Solr schema - complex type
I am trying to create a Solr schema that stores fields with more complex types. For example:
{
   "sessionId":413431,
   "sessionName":"Test Session"
   "gameDetails":[
      {
         "startTime":"2024-01-15T19:45:15Z",
         "displayName":"string"
      }
   ]
}


I created a schema - api/collections

{
  "name": "testComplex",
  "numShards": 4,
  "replicationFactor": 2
}


I added the first field set that is not complex - api/collections/testComplex/schema

{
    "add-field": [
        {
            "name": "sessionId",
            "type": "plong",
            "stored": true,
            "indexed": true
        },
        {
            "name": "sessionName",
            "type": "string",
            "stored": true,
            "indexed": true
        }
    ]
}


I added other field that should be complex - api/collections/complex/schema

{
    "add-field": [
        {
            "name": "gameDetails.startTime",
            "type": "pdate",
            "stored": true,
            "indexed": true
        },
        {
            "name": "gameDetails.displayName",
            "type": "string",
            "stored": true,
            "indexed": true
        }
    ]
}

but as a result, I have
"sessionId":413431,
"sessionName":"Test session",
"gameDetails.startTime":"2024-01-15T19:45:15Z",
"gameDetails.displayName":"test",

Could somebody suggest, what I am doing wrong and how to achieve it?

As far as I know, complex types are not supported in Solr, it will just flatten the nested field as it does in your example.
You are able to have child-documents, more about this here:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/indexing-nested-documents.html
